# Prevent CakePHP to create div with input field

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers, cakephp-3.2

Every time I create an input field using

```
$this->Form->input('name');
```

It creates a div element

```
<div class="input name">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent creation of div block around input field. Also, is there a way to add custom class to the `div` created? like

```
<div class="input name myStyle">
  <input>
</div>
```

I'm using `CakePHP 3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the templates. You can do this by creating a new config file:

**config/app_form.php**

```
return [
    'inputContainer' => '{{content}}'
];
```

Then load it in your View:

**src/View/AppView.php**

```
class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadHelper('Form', ['templates' => 'app_form']);
    }
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

Comment: I want this in element. Adding this in view will effect all forms throughout the application ?. I want this only on one input field

Comment: @anujsharma9196 then you can do `$this->Form->input('name', [
        'templates' => [
            'inputContainer' => '{{content}}'
        ]
    ]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
php echo $this->Form->create($user, ['type' => 'file', 'id'=>"change-profile-form",'role' => 'form','class'=>'orb-form']);

$this->Form->templates(['inputContainer' => '{{content}}']);


echo $this->Form->input('first_name', ['label'=>false, 'div'=>false, 'placeholder' => 'First name']);
```

I hope this would be help you.